# Sencha touch : How to make native application for android on window7

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I am new to mobile application development. I got stuck while creating native application for Android on a Windows 7 machine. I followed the steps below:

1. I have downloaded *Sencha Touch* and placed in my local machine (www directory). I also downloaded Sencha SDK Tools  to execute all commands. first i executed command: **sencha generate app GS ../GS**
2. Created simple program and its running in my browser. (http://localhost:8080/GS)
3. I have downloaded Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and installed in my system. I am here confused what path here need to give.
4. Open the packager.json file
   added: "versionCode":"1.0"
   changed : "platform":"Android"
   "sdkPath" : "What will be the sdk path. I am getting here confused. I have given C:\Windows\System32 i think this is wrong"  // how can i find android path ?
5. Next i  executed command : **sencha app build native.**
   ...
   ...
   `[info] packaging your application as a native app..
   Failed to create android project`

... is the error message I am getting.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**sdkpath** should contains the location of your **android-sdk** on your local machine.

```
"sdkPath":"C:/Users/vksharma/AppData/Local/Android/sdk",// put your android-sdk path here
```

For more details:
[Refer Sencha-2 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android)

For finding your android path,follow these steps:

1) Go to **start**.
2) Type **sdkmanager**. It will come if android is properly installed. Open it.
3) Below the Menu-bar **sdk-path** is given.

*Refer the snapshot:-*

[image: Android Sdk Manager]

Answer (score 0):

Once you downloaded the Android SDK folder, you have to keep that folder in your local directory.

That is the required path(where you have kept that android sdk folder in your local directory), you have to give in packager.json file.